# Capture UIScrollview containing video layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, avplayer

I've a `UIScrollview` which has "AVPlayerLayer" as a sublayer. The user can pinch-to-zoom, drag, and add images over the "AVPlayerLayer" inside the `UIScrollview`.

I want to capture the final state of the `UIScrollview` with user edits (adding images, zooming video, and dragging to specific section of it) as `UIImage`.

I tried different APIs like "renderincontext" and "drawviewhierarchyinrect", and I can get all  the `UIScrollview` contents as image but not including the "AVPlayerLayer".I can't also use "AVAssetImageGenerator" as it returns a video frame without current user edits.

If anyone can help.